# UIKit выравниванием после удаления объекта

Tags: html, dom, uikit

Здравствуйте! Удаляю на странице через DOM объекты, но после удаления, оставшиеся объекты перемещаются без выравнивания по сетке, как можно это исправить?
[image: скриншот ситуации]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   function removeElem(x) {
     var parent = document.getElementById("oldImages");
     var child = document.getElementById(x);
     parent.removeChild(child);
   }
  </script>
```

```html
<div class="uk-panel uk-margin-large-top" style="border: solid 1px black;">
    <form class="uk-form uk-grid uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-bottom" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="theForm" action="/admin/production/update_p">
      <div class="uk-form-row uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-top">
 <label class="uk-form-row">Название:</label>
 <input type="text"
        name="name"
        value="Test #3"
        class="uk-width-expand"
        data-parsley-trigger="change"
        required=""
        data-parsley-minlength="3"
        data-parsley-maxlength="100">
      </div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-2">
 <div class="uk-margin-top uk-margin-bottom uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-4" data-uk-grid-margin id="oldImages">
     <div id="img0">
       <a onclick='removeElem("img0")'>X</a>
       <img class="uk-thumbnail" src='/img/production/prostheses/uzor-vesennie-cvety-crochet-pattern-spring-flowers1.jpg'/>
       <input type="hidden" value="/img/production/prostheses/uzor-vesennie-cvety-crochet-pattern-spring-flowers1.jpg" name="oldimg[]">
     </div>
     <div id="img1">
       <a onclick='removeElem("img1")'>X</a>
       <img class="uk-thumbnail" src='/img/production/prostheses/u10244_7672_kotjenok_v_kruwke.jpg'/>
       <input type="hidden" value="/img/production/prostheses/u10244_7672_kotjenok_v_kruwke.jpg" name="oldimg[]">
     </div>
     <div id="img2">
       <a onclick='removeElem("img2")'>X</a>
       <img class="uk-thumbnail" src='/img/production/prostheses/rPj8NTCuk-s.jpg'/>
       <input type="hidden" value="/img/production/prostheses/rPj8NTCuk-s.jpg" name="oldimg[]">
     </div>
     <div id="img3">
       <a onclick='removeElem("img3")'>X</a>
       <img class="uk-thumbnail" src='/img/production/prostheses/resize.jpe'/>
       <input type="hidden" value="/img/production/prostheses/resize.jpe" name="oldimg[]">
     </div>
     <div id="img4">
       <a onclick='removeElem("img4")'>X</a>
       <img class="uk-thumbnail" src='/img/production/prostheses/pt-3009.jpg'/>
       <input type="hidden" value="/img/production/prostheses/pt-3009.jpg" name="oldimg[]">
     </div>
 </div>
```